# What python packages are installed by default on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu

Imagine having to write python code to be submitted to a remote Ubuntu box to be run there (you do not get to touch the terminal, you do not get to install anything or run apt to query what's installed). How would you go about figuring out what python packages are likely available on that machine by default (i.e. what does a complete Ubuntu install include, not what can I download and install later). I'm having the hardest time finding something like a "list of all packages installed by default" or some such thing. Is there such a thing? Or do I have to download an image and actually install it just to find out what's in the box?

Comment: You can try: `pip list`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to http://releases.ubuntu.com/ and select the specific version of Ubuntu. Then download the ".manifest" file (there can be more than one, e.g. desktop and server).  For example here is one recent file:
http://releases.ubuntu.com/20.04.1/ubuntu-20.04.1-live-server-amd64.manifest

Grep that for "python" and you'll see most of the relevant parts.  Some selected highlights from the above link:

```
python3 3.8.2-0ubuntu2
python3-automat 0.8.0-1ubuntu1
python3-blinker 1.4+dfsg1-0.3ubuntu1
python3-colorama    0.4.3-1build1
python3-configobj   5.0.6-4
python3-dbus    1.2.16-1build1
python3-idna    2.8-1
python3-jinja2  2.10.1-2
python3-jsonschema  3.2.0-0ubuntu2
python3-more-itertools  4.2.0-1build1
python3-oauthlib    3.1.0-1ubuntu2
python3-requests    2.22.0-2ubuntu1
python3-simplejson  3.16.0-2ubuntu2
python3-six 1.14.0-2
python3-twisted 18.9.0-11
python3-urllib3 1.25.8-2
python3-yaml    5.3.1-1
python3-zope.interface  4.7.1-1
```

Comment: That's a lot farther than I managed to get. Thank you. But does that really mean numpy and scipy and such are not available by default on ubuntu?

Comment: Correct, NumPy is not installed by default (on any mainstream OS, as far as I know).